How much RAM to run Llama locally?
On a server, I only have a CPU and a simulated GPU with 4mb simulated VRAM. So basically I only have a CPU.
I want to install Llama 2 13b locally. How much RAM is recommended?

There is a lot of information here

In the course "Prompt Engineering for Llama 2" on DeepLearning.AI, taught by Amit Sangani from Meta, there is a notebook in which it says the following:


Note that only the Llama 2 7B chat model (by default the 4-bit    quantized version is downloaded) may work fine locally.
Other larger sized models could require too much memory (13b models    generally require at least 16GB of RAM and 70b models at least 64GB
of RAM) and run too slowly.


